# Get arguments using Request instance in Slim php

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to get the $args from $request, is there any way to do it, if so how,
here is a sample of what i am doing:

```
class JwtMiddleware
{

    public function __construct($settings)
    {

    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler)
    {
        $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
        $id = $route->getArgument('user_id');
        // this doesn't work

        /*
         //
         code 
         //
        */

    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the route arguments from the request, you can do the following:

```php
use Slim\Routing\RouteContext;
// ...

$routeContext = RouteContext::fromRequest($request);
$route = $routeContext->getRoute();
        
$userId = $route->getArgument('user_id');

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have sent any data with your http request. There are to common ways with different techniques of getting a hand on your data.

1. Via GET-Method
   You can send data within your url. You can then receive them with the following function call:

   $data = $request->getAttribute('name_of_argument');
2. Via POST & PUT-Method
   You can also transfer your data as json in your http body. You can then receive your data in the following matter:

   $data = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);

However data can be also send as simple attribute, for example within a POST-Method. Therefore you can use the following code to get your data:

```
$data = $request->getParsedBody();
```

Hands up for using Slim!

Comment: I don't actually want it to be in the body, i want to send the data in my url, like this /users/{user_id}/register for example, i tried your first method, to get the attribute but i get nothing when i echo it, echo ($request->getAttribute('user_id'))

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be somewhere else. I saw that you are using the concept of middleware. You might try to echo the handled user_id in your main slim logic. If that works the issue may be found in your middleware logic.